# Two way binding angular component with parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular component (vendor-filters) that I would like to pass data to and from a parent controller.  The purpose is to create a filter off of mainInfo, and pass that data back to the parent controller where it will reflect the filtering in the component. My problem is that this mainInfo variable is returning undefined in the component controller.  Here's my code :

html

```
<div ng-controller="kanban as ctrl">
<vendor-filters mainInfo="ctrl.mainInfo"></vendor-filters>
<div class="qt-kb">
    <kanban-list label="Incoming" type="incoming" cards="ctrl.mainInfo.incoming"></kanban-list>
    <kanban-list label="In Progress" type="progress" cards="ctrl.mainInfo.inProgress"></kanban-list>
    <kanban-list label="Waiting For Documentation" type="docs" cards="ctrl.mainInfo.documentation"></kanban-list>
    <kanban-list label="Pending Approval" type="closed" cards="ctrl.mainInfo.closed"></kanban-list>
</div>
```

Parent Controller :

```
app.controller("kanban", ["$scope", "assignmentDataService", "globalSpinner",  function ($scope, assignmentDataService, globalSpinner) {

const vm = this;
vm.mainInfo = [];

activate();

function activate() {
    getData();
}

  function getData() {
    var promise = assignmentDataService.getData()
        .then(function(data) {
            vm.mainInfo = data;
        });

    globalSpinner.register(promise);
};

}]);
```

Component controller:

```
class VendorFilterCtrl {
constructor($http, $scope, $timeout,assignmentDataService) {
    this.$scope = $scope
    this.$http = $http;

    const vm = this;
    //I could be initializing this wrong but this is where I'm trying to get 
    //the data. 
     vm.data = vm.mainInfo;               

}
app.controller('kanban').component("vendorFilters", {
templateUrl: "app/components/vendorFilters.html",
bindings: {
    store: "=?store",
    onChange: '&',
    mainInfo: '<'
},

controller: VendorFilterCtrl,
controllerAs: "ctrl",
bindToController: true
 });
```

Basically I'm trying to get the mainInfo from the parent controller into the component and visa versa. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: can you reproduce error, and provide a live demo

Answer (score 1):

Start by using kebab-case for the attribute:

```
 <vendor-filters  ̶m̶a̶i̶n̶I̶n̶f̶o̶ main-info="ctrl.mainInfo"></vendor-filters>
```

---

#### NEXT

Fix this:

```
app ̶.̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶(̶'̶k̶a̶n̶b̶a̶n̶'̶)̶ .component("vendorFilters", {
```

Comment: I changed it to kebab-case but it's still not giving me the data from the controller into the component.